# Mapbox integration with Cartodb

Tags: mapbox, integration

We are using Mapbox Mobile SDK for Android application Development. We have used our own Maps Data SETs for POIs and Addresses.  These custom POIs are not available to us in Search and Creating Routes.  Is there a possibility of using Custom Maps with our own POIs and implement search through Cartodb?